# Forwardslashes becomes attributes with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

When I replace the html of an element, my url path turns into attributes:
assets="", images="", hello.jpg="". What's the problem?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var newHTML = '';
  newHTML += '<div class="product-image" style="background-image: url("assets/images/hello.jpg")"></div>';

  $('.main').html(newHTML);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now your `style` attribute is ending after `url(` because you're using the same type of quotation mark that opened the attribute. Here are two options:

1. Remove the quotation marks in your URL string:

`newHTML += '<div class="product-image" style="background-image: url(assets/images/hello.jpg);"></div>';`

2. Or mix your quotation marks by using single quotes around the URL, but don't forget to escape them with a backslash because you're in a JavaScript string:

`newHTML += '<div class="product-image" style="background-image: url(\'assets/images/hello.jpg\');"></div>';`

Answer (score 0):

Within the style attribute there are additional double quotes for the `url(...)` value. These will need to be single quotes that are escaped so they are not considered the end of the attribute value.

```
var newHTML = '<div class="product-image" style="background-image: url(\'assets/images/hello.jpg\')"></div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the nested double quotes. You could try this instead:

```
var newHTML = $('<div class="product-image"></div>');
newHTML.css("background-image", 'url("assets/images/hello.jpg")');
$('.main').html(newHTML);
```